# tag:testflight same signature issue android

Tags: testflight

After uploading my new build (production) to Test Flight, when I try to install my app it says already used signature with the same app name. Is it possible to install app over Test flight without uninstalling old one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the production build and "beta" build is signed with a different key. You will need to uninstall the previous build first.